# Get WooCommerce Email Classes in Backend

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How to get all available WooCommerce email classes in WordPress admin page. I want to get all classes `(WC_Email_New_Order, WC_Email_Cancelled_Order)` etc.
I have tried `woocommerce_email_classes` filter but i am not able to get the classes.

## UPDATE

I added the following

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'my_email_classes', 10, 1);

function my_email_classes( $emails ){
    $mailer = WC()->mailer();
    $mails = $mailer->get_emails();

    $mails['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']->template_html = MY_TEMPLATE_PATH.'test.php';

    return $mails;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "get all available WooCommerce email classes"? Do you mean somethink like that `$my_var = new WC_Email_New_Order()` ?

Comment: I thought the same. But i read somewhere that creating object causes duplicate emails to send @user141080

Comment: `wc()->mailer->emails` would give you all the email `class` instances. The same that you'd get from the `woocommerce_email_classes` filter. The email `class` files (e.g. `class-wc-email-new-order.php`) are stored in `woocommerce/includes/emails`, and the `class` names are the *keys* of the `array` passed via the `woocommerce_email_classes` filter.

Comment: I mean, `wc()->mailer()`.

Comment: No problem @melvin. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: @SallyCJ I will mark it an answer if you post it in answer section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like I've pointed in my *comment*, you can use `wc()->mailer()->emails`, which would give you a list of all the email `class` *instances*. Example:

```
// Get all the email class instances.
$emails = wc()->mailer()->emails;

// Prints all the email class names.
var_dump( array_keys( $emails ) );

// Access the default subject for new order email notifications.
$subject = $emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->get_default_subject();
```

The same '$emails' can also be accessed from within a callback function hooked to the [`woocommerce_email_classes`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Emails.html#206) filter. Here is an example for overriding a specific class:

```
// By default, $emails is an array of '{CLASS NAME}' => {The class instance}.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', function( $emails ){
    $emails['WC_Email_New_Order'] = include 'path/to/your/custom/class.php';
    /* Or if the class file is already "included":
    $emails['WC_Email_New_Order'] = new My_Custom_WC_Email_New_Order_Class();
    */

    return $emails;
} );
```

And (although you may already know) the email `class` files (e.g. `class-wc-email-new-order.php`) are stored in `woocommerce/includes/emails`.

---

### A better way to access the `emails` property (or the `class` *instances*)

Use `wc()->mailer()->get_emails()`, *except from within a callback function hooked to the `woocommerce_email_classes` filter*.

```
// Both of these work, but the latter is preferred.
$emails = wc()->mailer()->emails;
$emails = wc()->mailer()->get_emails();
```

---

### Additional Code

(**These are in reply to your *comments* as well as the "UPDATE" part in your *question*.**)

> Can I use the `$emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->template_html` to force
>   custom template selection?

Yes, you can. However, the value needs to be a path relative to the *custom WooCommerce templates directory in your theme*; e.g. `wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce`. So:

```
// This works, if wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/emails/your-custom-template.php
// exists.
$emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->template_html = 'emails/your-custom-template.php';

// But this doesn't work, even if the file exists.
$emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->template_html = '/absolute/path/to/your-custom-template.php';
```

If you want to use an *absolute* path (e.g. in your custom plugin folder), you can use the [`woocommerce_locate_core_template`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#840) filter:

```
// $a and $b can be ignored, but $file and $id are important
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_core_template', function( $file, $a, $b, $id ){
    if ( 'new_order' === $id ) {
        return '/absolute/path/to/your-custom-template.php';
    }

    return $file;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Can i use the `$emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->template_html` to force custom template selection?

Comment: I  assigned `$emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->template_html` to a new path still template is taken from woocommerce

Comment: Can i overwrite the template path from woocommerce `$mailer` ? I think when i call  `$emails = wc()->mailer()->emails` new instance in created ?

Comment: Does the relative path need to be from theme ?

Comment: Yes, for the `template_html` property. But there's another way you can use. However, I'll post that in about 1 hour later. I hope you don't mind..