# How can i access woocommerce order variables inside shortcode?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I am adding a shortcode from wordpress to woocommerce email template.

```
do_shortcode('[sample_test name="additional_gift_msg"]);
```

Then i am using this to display the value in email. I am able to display value.

```
function th_email_shortcode_handler( $atts ) {
    if ( ! empty( $atts['name'] ) ) {
        $field = $atts['name'];
        echo 'Found me';
    }
}
add_shortcode('sample_test','th_email_shortcode_handler');
```

But i need `$order` or `$order_id` inside this handler function to take some value from post meta. How can i use those variables? The shortcode handler function is in functions.php

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce Email template already has access to `$order` variable. You simply need to add it to shortcode atts, like this

```
do_shortcode('[sample_test name="additional_gift_msg" order_id=' . $order->get_id() . ']');
```

Then in the shortcode callback:

```
function th_email_shortcode_handler( $atts ) {
    // get the $order_id
    $order_id = $atts['order_id'];

    // create the order object if needed
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( ! empty( $atts['name'] ) ) {
        $field = $atts['name'];
        echo 'Found me';
    }
}
```

Comment: still $order_id is null when var_dumped @Manzoor

Comment: How are you trying to add that information to the email template? Using the hook or by placing the template in `woocommerce` directory in the theme?

Comment: I have a custom email template and that email template is passed to woocommerce. When i var_dump `$order` in email template it shows required value. But i am not getting value in function

Comment: Can you please show/explain how you pass the template to WooCommerce?

Comment: using `woocommerce_locate_template` hook

Comment: That hook won't give you access to the `$order` object as it's a more generic hook. The best way to use a custom email template is to add the template to woocommerce directory of the theme and use the solution as given in the answer. If you are using it in a plugin then use `woocommerce_email_classes`

Comment: I tried woocommerce_email_classes but it won't even change the path

Comment: You are using it in a plugin or theme?

Comment: plugin. Check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/312576/130740

Comment: So you are suggesting to include the template file using `woocommerce_email_classes` like this `$this->emails['WC_Email_New_Order']                 = include 'emails/class-wc-email-new-order.php';`

Comment: Yes, then you need to provide your plugin template path to the filter.

Comment: That's a great idea. Let me check

Comment: Is it possible to set template using woocommerce_email_classes when front end loads /